# the tag <mesh> is unrecognized in the browser

Tags: reactjs, browser, three.js, mesh, uppercase

The tag <mesh> is not recognized in the browser. I am building a react and three.js project for which my 3D model is not loading. I tried many ways by seeing the documentation and other things but it was not working. This is my code.

```
import { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei';
import CanvasLoader from '../Loader';

const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF('./desktop_pc/scene.gltf');

  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <primitive object={computer.scene} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputerCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default Computers;
```

I tried it seeing and implementing the official documentation but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `export default Computers` type `export default ComputerCanvas`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75724084/), instead of exporting default computers, use  `export default  ComputersCanvas`.

And in the Hero file, add
`import ComputersCanvas from "./canvas/Computers"`;